# Out of memory error when writing bson to disk

Tags: python, json, mongodb, bson

I've built a massive dictionary - which is probably around several hundred gigabytes. Is there a smart way to store such an object. I'm using the following routines to push to disk:

```
print "Writing to file..."
                jsontext = bson.dumps(sample_dict)
                f = open(predump_file, 'wb+')
                f.write(jsontext)
                f.close()
```

here is the stack trace I get:

```
Writing to file...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Combine.py", line 1331, in <module>
    jsontext = bson.dumps(sample_dict)
  File "/mnt/opt/Centos5.8/python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/__init__.py", line 69, in dumps
    return encode_document(obj, [], generator_func = generator)
  File "/mnt/opt/Centos5.8/python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/codec.py", line 207, in encode_document
    encode_value(name, value, buf, traversal_stack, generator_func)
  File "/mnt/opt/Centos5.8/python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/codec.py", line 177, in encode_value
    traversal_stack, generator_func))
MemoryError: out of memory
```

The choices (I can currently only think of these):

1. The dictionary is nested - so essentially split the dictionary - into layers.
2. Split the dictionary on the first key and provide another index to these underlying dictionaries. I can then store N dictionaries independently. If this is good is there any recommended way to split a dictionary of its keys and produce a top layer index dictionary. I'm thinking that each sub dictionary must be a variable. So once we have we have the big nested dictionary, we could say divide it into N smaller dictionaries and have a mapping index sitting on the top.
3. Is MongoDB a potential solution here?

Comment: Can you show some of your dictionary content? what is the depth of the nested dictionary? personally I would use a database to achieve this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mongo db maximum (bson) document size is 16MB. You can't store data with size of bigger than that.
You can store each `key value` as a document in your collection.
In your case you can use `key` field as `_id` property for your documt

Comment: Good to know about this limit

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on the content of your dict and the way you want to retrieve data later on. I would choose the second method if I were you.